# Hide menu outclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am writing menu for responsive website, but I am stunned in one moment - hide menu when outclick...
**I would really appreciate any help with my bugged jQuery :)** - [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stefan2518/5cs17o7h/)

```js
function hamburgerClick()
{
 $('#hamburgerMenu').click(function(e) // (hide || show) menu by clicking "hamburgerMenu" icon
 {
  e.preventDefault();

  if( $('#hamburgerMenu').hasClass('is-active') )
  {
   $('#hamburgerMenu').removeClass('is-active');
   $('#menu').removeClass('is-active');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#hamburgerMenu').addClass('is-active');
   $('#menu').addClass('is-active');
  }
 });
}


function hideMenuOutclick() /* does not work */
{
 if( $('#hamburgerMenu').hasClass('is-active') )
 {
  $(document).click(function(e)
  {
   if( ($(e.target).closest('#menu').length!==0) ||
       ($(e.target).closest('#hamburgerMenu').length!==0) )
    {
     $('#hamburgerMenu').removeClass('is-active');
     $('#menu').removeClass('is-active');
    }
  });
 }
}



function beginJS()
{
 hamburgerClick();
 hideMenuOutclick();
 /* few more scripts */
}

window.onload = beginJS;
```

```css
.bg-red
{
 background-color: #e32624;
}
/********** pure header **********/
#header
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 56px;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
}
/********** fixing Comission **********/
.fixingComission
{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
 height: 56px;
 appearance: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-radius: none;
 background-color: #e32624;
 transition: background 0.3s;
}
.fixingComission a
{
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 12px;
}
/********** hamburger button **********/
#hamburgerMenu
{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 56px;
 height: 56px;
 font-size: 0;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 appearance: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-radius: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #e32624;
 transition: background 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu:focus
{
 outline: none;
}
/********** hamburger button span **********/
#hamburgerMenu span
{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: 12px;
 right: 12px;
 height: 5px;
 background: white;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span::before,
#hamburgerMenu span::after
{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 content: "";
}
#hamburgerMenu span::before
{
  top: -14px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s, top 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span::after
{
  bottom: -14px;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span:focus
{
 outline: none;
}
/********** hamburger button active - class added onclick by JS **********/
#hamburgerMenu.is-active
{
 background-color: #bc1a18;
}
/********** hamburger button span active **********/
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span
{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::before,
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::after
{
  width: 50%;
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::before
{
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(22px) translateY(2px) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::after
{
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(22px) translateY(-2px) rotate(-45deg);
}
/********** navigation **********/
#menu
{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color: #003e78;
 
 overflow: hidden;
 -webknit-overflow-scroll: touch; /* for mobile safari */
 
 top: 56px;
 width: 65%;
 height: 100%;
 left: -65%;
 transition-property: opacity, left;
 transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.5s;
}
#menu.is-active
{
 left: 0;
}
#menu ul
{
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-right: 0; /* exact value is given by JS to hide scrollbar */
}
#menu ul::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    display: none; 
}
#menu ul li
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 52px;
}
#menu ul li.current,
#menu ul li:hover,
#menu ul li:active
{
 background-color: #0066c5;
}
#menu ul li a
{
 display: block;
 height: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header" class="bg-red">
  
  <button class="fixingComission">
   <a href="index-5.html">Zleć naprawę</a>
  </button>
  
  <button id="hamburgerMenu"><span>toggle menu</span></button>
  
  <nav id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-1.html">O nas</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-2.html">Serwis</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-3.html">W sumie to nie wiem</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-4.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-5.html">Zleć naprawę</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
 </header>
```

*//hamburgerClick is working, but hideMenuOutclick is not.*

*I know, that on jsfiddle project isn't working, but it works on localhost and srv with implemented jQuery v1.10.2*

**I would be really grateful to tip about scrolling in CSS3:**

Why despite "overflow: auto" '$("#menu").onMouseOver' is still scrolling whole page? Is it possible to force scrolling some element (even if it is full-viewed in computer screen), not whole page?

**EDIT:** Hiding menu is done with click event (which will be matched for invalids and it won't be click - really thanks to point this out!) Now only thing is this scrolling :)

Comment: Specifically I'm going to call attention to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38317768/497418) because it handles accessibility

Comment: Can you please change your comment to answer, that i may accept as a best one? If you would add "why the scrolling is wrong" i would really appreciate :) //even if not, your answer is still best

Comment: No, I've already closed this question as a duplicate. It's not possible to add any new answers to this. Your question will stay active so that any future visitors are funneled into the linked duplicate. Regarding your edit, if you have a new question you'd like to ask, please ask it as a separate question. Please be sure to [thoroughly research possible solutions before asking to avoid asking another duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the jsfiddle bug the problem is in this line:

```
if( $('#hamburgerMenu').hasClass('is-active') ) {
```

If the menu is not active on document load the event handler never be attached.

The [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5cs17o7h/8/): the errors here are: jquery missing, load type: wrap in the head.

I assume you want to close the menu when clicking outside the menu.

For the second part of your question I figured out the problem is related to the height of the #menu: change it from 100% to 50%.

The snippet:

```js
function hamburgerClick()
{
  $('#hamburgerMenu').click(function(e) // (hide || show) menu by clicking "hamburgerMenu" icon
                            {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( $('#hamburgerMenu').hasClass('is-active') )
    {
      $('#hamburgerMenu').removeClass('is-active');
      $('#menu').removeClass('is-active');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#hamburgerMenu').addClass('is-active');
      $('#menu').addClass('is-active');
    }
  });
}


function hideMenuOutclick() /* does not work */
{
  $(document).click(function(e)
                    {
    if( ($(e.target).closest('#menu').length==0) &&
       ($(e.target).closest('#hamburgerMenu').length==0) )
    {
      if( $('#hamburgerMenu').hasClass('is-active') ) {
        $('#hamburgerMenu').removeClass('is-active');
        $('#menu').removeClass('is-active');
      }
    }
  });
}



function beginJS()
{
  hamburgerClick();
  hideMenuOutclick();
  /* few more scripts */
}

window.onload = beginJS;
```

```css
.bg-red
{
  background-color: #e32624;
}
/********** pure header **********/
#header
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
/********** fixing Comission **********/
.fixingComission
{
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 56px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  background-color: #e32624;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}
.fixingComission a
{
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
/********** hamburger button **********/
#hamburgerMenu
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #e32624;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu:focus
{
  outline: none;
}
/********** hamburger button span **********/
#hamburgerMenu span
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span::before,
#hamburgerMenu span::after
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
}
#hamburgerMenu span::before
{
  top: -14px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s, top 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span::after
{
  bottom: -14px;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
}
#hamburgerMenu span:focus
{
  outline: none;
}
/********** hamburger button active - class added onclick by JS **********/
#hamburgerMenu.is-active
{
  background-color: #bc1a18;
}
/********** hamburger button span active **********/
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span
{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::before,
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::after
{
  width: 50%;
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::before
{
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(22px) translateY(2px) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburgerMenu.is-active span::after
{
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(22px) translateY(-2px) rotate(-45deg);
}
/********** navigation **********/
#menu
{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #003e78;

  overflow: hidden;
  -webknit-overflow-scroll: touch; /* for mobile safari */

  top: 56px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 50%;
  left: -65%;
  transition-property: opacity, left;
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.5s;
}
#menu.is-active
{
  left: 0;
}
#menu ul
{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0; /* exact value is given by JS to hide scrollbar */
}
#menu ul::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  display: none;
}
#menu ul li
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
}
#menu ul li.current,
#menu ul li:hover,
#menu ul li:active
{
  background-color: #0066c5;
}
#menu ul li a
{
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<header id="header" class="bg-red">

    <button class="fixingComission">
        <a href="index-5.html">Zleć naprawę</a>
    </button>

    <button id="hamburgerMenu"><span>toggle menu</span></button>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Start</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-1.html">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-2.html">Serwis</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-3.html">W sumie to nie wiem</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-4.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-5.html">Zleć naprawę</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: i updated fiddle by adding some useless words and your menuHeight change does not work, but thanks for working version of hiding menu :)